# Enviar dados do aplicativo com tela do celular bloqueada para o servidor utilizando comando de voz

Tags: android, web-service, services

Boa tarde.

Gostaria de saber se tem uma maneira de criar um serviço na minha aplicação em que quando o usuário falasse algo pega-se o conteúdo do que ele falou e envia-se para o servidor, porém com o celular bloqueado, ou seja, sem ele informar a senha para acessar o celular para depois falar algo. É igual a ideia do Google Now, porém iterando com a minha aplicação criada. A ideia é que ocorra uma interatividade rápida entre o usuário e a aplicação sem realizar várias etapas, como, por exemplo, clicar várias vezes na tela para executar determinada ação.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Oi Giancardo, não ficou claro para mim o que você está tentando fazer (o texto está denso). Se a ideia é iniciar uma ação no seu aplicativo mesmo com a tela bloqueado, conforme [essa resposta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28327029/664577) parece que a biblioteca [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid) faz isso.